# Action bar one click go to url (Webview)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I made the application of this tutorial:

[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JM-NkUwng1Y)

Here I made the Web View and each button refreshes one page. Unfortunately, this is a problem because you have to push to TWICE the page is refreshed . How to do it properly to work on first click ?

MainActivity.cs:

```
LinearLayout linTest = (LinearLayout)ActionBar.CustomView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
            LinearLayout linTest2 = (LinearLayout)ActionBar.CustomView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout2);
            LinearLayout linTest3 = (LinearLayout)ActionBar.CustomView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout3);
            LinearLayout linTest4 = (LinearLayout)ActionBar.CustomView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout4);

            linTest.Click += linTest_Click;
            linTest2.Click += linTest2_Click;
            linTest3.Click += linTest3_Click;
            linTest4.Click += linTest4_Click;


        }

        void linTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
            //ur code here
            web_view.LoadUrl ("http://www.onet.pl");
        }

        void linTest2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
            //ur code here
            web_view.LoadUrl ("http://www.wp.pl");
        }

        void linTest3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
            //ur code here
            web_view.LoadUrl ("http://www.interia.pl");
        }

        void linTest4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
            //ur code here
            web_view.LoadUrl ("http://www.google.pl");
        }
```

log (two click):

```
[SpannableStringBuilder] SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
[SpannableStringBuilder] SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
[WebView] loadUrlImpl: called
[webcore]  CORE loadUrl: called
[webkit] Firewall not null
[webkit] euler: isUrlBlocked = false
[WebView] loadUrlImpl: called
[WebCore] uiOverrideUrlLoading: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returnstrue
[GATE] <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
[webcore]  CORE loadUrl: called
[webkit] Firewall not null
[webkit] euler: isUrlBlocked = false
[GATE] <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
```

My problem (screen):
[link](http://zapodaj.net/6e9be75354372.jpg.html)

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? Maybe you can add some screenshots and more code to explain what the problem is. (The grammar in your questions is a bit weird too, could you fix that too?)

Comment: My problem: http://zapodaj.net/6e9be75354372.jpg.html

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading". See the documentation of Android on this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29
Are you overriding that function?

I don't see any other code in your edit, so i can't say anything on the implementation your have there. I would like to see the function where you add the click handlers.

Comment: `public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
 {
  public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
  {
   view.LoadUrl (url);
   return true;
  }
 }
`

Comment: So why do you override ShouldOverrideUrlLoading ? It is not necessary to do that, you can just instantiate the webview and call LoadUrl()

Comment: or how to do it best ?

Comment: Just remove the override.

Comment: My app: http://host1gb.net.pl/download.php?file=9a3239af93a9c95ae10bbe8137144678
You can take a look ? I have no idea;/